# SwiftUI Text justified alignment

Tags: text, swiftui, text-alignment

Has anyone found a way to align the string in a `Text` in a justified way?

In my reading app I'd like to offer the user to choose the justified alignment, where both the `.leading` both the `.trailing` alignments are true at the same time. Unfortunately the `.multilineTextAlignment` modifier for the `Text` has only three options: `.leading`, `.center` and `.trailing`.

If not I can still wrap an `UILabel` into a `UIViewRepresentable` since the `UILabel` has the `.justified` alignment option, but I thought it should be available in the `Text` as well and I was not able to find it.

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm late but I faced same issue , I will write it here, it could help other developer in future

Unfortunately until now Apple doesn't suppourt `.justified` in SwiftUI 2.0

you need to depend on UIKit

Add this code in your project

```
   struct LabelAlignment: UIViewRepresentable {
    var text: String
    var textAlignmentStyle : TextAlignmentStyle
    var width: CGFloat

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UILabel {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment(rawValue: textAlignmentStyle.rawValue)!
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.preferredMaxLayoutWidth = width
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        label.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)

        return label
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UILabel, context: Context) {
        uiView.text = text
    }
}

enum TextAlignmentStyle : Int{
     case left = 0 ,center = 1 , right = 2 ,justified = 3 ,natural = 4
}
```

Then use it like this

```
LabelAlignment(text: "Your text here", textAlignmentStyle: .justified, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 20)
```

change 20 to any number you like to add space on left and right

my solution will will depend on text content size
if the text is small the view will be small and vice versa
so it will act as Text()